# I'm building addon for firefox user can take screenshot, but browser.runtime.sendMessage returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to implement a function that user can take screenshot using `browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab` .

But browser.runtime.sendMessage immediately returns undefined.

In `console.log("dataUrl ::: ", dataUrl)` of `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener` it logged data url, so it's working. But somehow, it's undefined in `screenshot.addEventListener` 
My current code is as below. It works fine in chrome(I changed browser with chrome of course).

I appreciate any advice.

// manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "storage", "webRequest", "<all_urls>"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
```

// popup.js

```
screenshot.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    const response = await browser.runtime.sendMessage({
      type: "takeScreenshot",
    });
    console.log("response is ", response); // undefined
    if (response.dataUrl) {
      const img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = response.dataUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending message:", error);
  }
});
```

// background.js

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  
  if (message.type === "takeScreenshot") {
    const option = { active: true, currentWindow: true }; 
    await browser.tabs.query(option, async (tabs) => {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      if (!activeTab) {
        await sendResponse({ error: "No active tab." });
        return;
      }
      await browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
        activeTab.windowId,
        { format: "png" },
       
        async (dataUrl) => {
          if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
            await sendResponse({ error: browser.runtime.lastError.message });

            return;
          }
          console.log("dataUrl ::: ", dataUrl); //it logs correct dataUrl

          await sendResponse({ dataUrl: dataUrl }); 
        }
       
      );
    });
    return true;
  }
});
```

I enabled the “<all_urls>” permission in the Add-ons Manager according to [this](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/browser-tabs-capturevisibletab-not-working-in-firefox-for-mv3/122965/2) .
But it still returns same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the background script and messaging in this case - just use captureVisibleTab in the popup! But, assuming you want to use the background script, the problem is that you've incorrectly used Chrome's atavistic `return true` in a Firefox's async onMessage.

In Firefox you **simply return the value** just like you do in any async code:

```js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender) => {
  if (message.type === 'takeScreenshot') {
    const [{windowId}] = await browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
    const dataUrl = await browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab(windowId, {format: 'png'});
    return {dataUrl};
  }
});
```

The exceptions are automatically sent to your calling code's `catch`, no need to catch them here.

There may be other causes for not receving a response:

- another `onMessage` listener returns something earlier
- using a libary to promisify `browser`, which is not necessary for Firefox
- loading the background script in html
- pausing the listener in devtools debugger

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion but still response in screenshot.addEventListener is undefined.

Comment: Thanks!! I just moved captureVisibleTab in popup.js and it worked!!
```
screenshot.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    let response;
    const [{ windowId }] = await browser.tabs.query({
      active: true, currentWindow: true,});
    const dataUrl = await browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab(windowId, {
      format: "png",
    });
    response = { dataUrl };
    if (response.dataUrl) {
      const img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = response.dataUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

Observation #1:

It seems to be in fashion lately for people to add “await” outside of functions; probably thinking that it’ll make them run asynchronously, but it doesn’t work like that… a function has to be async by design (ie: promise) to be compatible with await.

Observation #2:

Your “return true” under *browser.runtime.onMessage*, is illegal and utterly useless and may well be making your function terminate prematurely.

Comment out “return true;” as well as all those “await”s and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion but still response in screenshot.addEventListener is undefined.